# Please explain the difference between 'on-the-job training' and 'on job training'

Tags: word-usage

I know the phrase 'on- the- job training'. But, I am confused with the use 'on job training' in the following sentence. Please explain the difference between them.

> We have really turned our back on job training.

Comment: [turned our back on] [job training] "turn our back on" is a set phrase.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan said, **"Turned our back on"** is a set phrase which means to *move away from*.

**Job training** is just training for a job, fairly self-explanatory.